# AngularJS: Checking the radio button and added a new partial at the end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have been using AngularJS for a while now. I have my a radio button which gives users the option and json data that has the value of the correct answers. I want to check the number of correct answers the user has provided(after the user clicks 'submit button') and then display it at the end of the test. How do I achieve it?

COntrollers.js

```
var testControllers = angular.module('testControllers', []);


 testControllers.controller('AnsaController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.check = function check(){
    alert("He");
  };
}]);
testControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
  });
}]);

testControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
    if($routeParams.itemId > 0){
        $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) - 1;
    }
    else{
        $scope.prevItem = $scope.questions.length - 1;
    }


    if($routeParams.itemId < $scope.questions.length-1){
        $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) + 1;
    }
    else{
        $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }
  });
}]);
```

JSON data:

```
[{
    "pos": "A",
    "val": "3"
}, {
    "pos": "B",
    "val": "6"
}, {
    "pos": "C",
    "val": "9"
}, {
    "pos": "D",
    "val": "0"
}, {
    "answer": "B"
}]
```

HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
<section class="artistinfo" ng-controller = "AnsaController">
    <div class="mcq" ng-model = "questions">
      <center><a href = "#details/{{prevItem}}" class = "button">PREV</a>
      <a href = "#details/{{nextItem}}" class = "button">NEXT</a></center>
      <div class = "qanda">
        <h3 class = "qnum">QUESTION {{parseInt(whichItem)+1}}</h3>
        <p class = "ques" math-jax-bind = "questions[whichItem].ques"></p>    
        <ul ng-show = "tab!= 1 || selopt==null">
              <li class= "optlist" ng-repeat="item in questions[whichItem].opts">
              <label class="formgroup">
              <input type="radio" name = "q" ng-model = "$parent.selopt" value = "{{item.pos}}"><span math-jax-bind = "item.val"></span>
             </label>
             </li>
             <center><button class = "button" ng-click = "tab = 1" ng-click = "check();"></button></center>

        </ul>
        <div ng-show = "selopt !=null">
            <p class = "ques" ng-show = "tab === 1">Your answer has been recorded! </p>
        </div>
              <p class = "ques">You've chosen: {{selopt}}</p>
      </div>
      <center><a href = "#list" class = "button">List View</a></center>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Comment: You can store the user's answers in sessionStorage and retrieve it when you need it. Note that sessionStorage only stores data on the current tab and when you close it then the data will be deleted. If you want multi-tab sessionStorage refer to [this](http://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/)

Comment: How do I compare after the submit button has been clicked?

Comment: on your submit button.. ng-click="submitFunction()" and handle the logic in your angular controller. ex: $scope.submitFunction() = function() { $scope.tab = 1; // add logic to save the answers in the sessionStorage }

Comment: It is not working. I will update my question

Comment: you added ng-click twice. Remove the first one and retain ng-click="check()". Now on your check function add $scope.tab = 1 and the logic to save your answers to sessionStorage